# Django all auth multiple user type

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

Im trying to implement two user types while using all-auth out of the box with django 1.11 cookiecutter. 
Ive tried the solution here [Multiple user type sign up with django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505242/multiple-user-type-sign-up-with-django-allauth)

But the seeker type one to one relationship is never created only the user.

Anyone implement this before?

TIA

Models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import config.settings.base as settings



@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):

    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': self.username})


class Seeker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_location = models.ForeignKey('location.Location', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Seeker"
        verbose_name_plural = "Seekers"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Form

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from .models import Seeker, Employer


class SeekerSignUpForm(SignupForm):

    def save(self, request):
        # Save the User instance and get a reference to it
        user_seeker = super(SeekerSignUpForm, self).save(request)
        # Create an instance of your model with the extra fields
        # then save it.
        # (N.B: the are already cleaned, but if you want to do some
        # extra cleaning just override the clean method as usual)
        seeker_user = Seeker.objects.get_or_create(user=user_seeker)
        seeker_user.save()
        return seeker_user.user
```

View

```
class SeekerSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'account/signup_seeker.html'
    form_class = SeekerSignUpForm
    view_name = 'seeker_signup'
```